# Threading and stucked GUI update for Animations

Tags: wpf, multithreading, progress-bar

The title sounds like some easy well-known problem, but please check out this:

I've got some WPF window that handles a list of `Threads` and shows `ProgressBar` for each `Thread`. The invoked GUI refresh is working for most threads showing right number of percent and also for unknown progress the `IsIndeterminate` state is animated. After the thread is done some animation fades out the `ProgressBar`.

However, for some of my heavy tasks the `ProgressBar` is not visually updated. For example, the `IsIndeterminate` state refreshes only if I force the GUI to redraw by some mouseover events or by moving the form. The fade out animation shows the same problem.

I think this is no usual stucking because the UI thread is not blocked by further operations (there's only one invoke setting `IsIndeterminate = true`). Until now, I wasn't able to find out what's the different between heavy tasks that result in this behavoir and tasks that do not.

Please notice that the replacement of the `Thread` by a `BackgroundWorker` shows exactly the same problem (I'm also not sure why people say `BackgroundWorker` will not freeze the GUI but `Threads` allegedly do - this seems not entirely right). Please also notice that although the thread is paused by `Thread.Suspend()` (yes, I know it's obsolete but this is an essential feature I need, since the task content is unknown) the GUI will not show up the `IsIndeterminate` animation if no other GUI element forces the refresh of the window.

Any ideas what that problem might be and how to fix it? I just need the usual refreshing rate for drawing animated controls...

Comment: Can you include a simple code sample to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Delete all that and use proper DataBinding.